# Obtener fecha con el siguiente formato "22 de agosto de 2019"

Tags: c#

Con el siguiente código `txtFechaElaboracion.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();`
obtengo: "jueves, 22 de agosto de 2019", pero lo que quiero que me muestre es "22 de agosto de 2019".
De antemano, gracias al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: Probaste con algun formato?

Comment: @Srsole Excelente, eso era lo que necesitaba así lo resolví label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy"); si lo pones como respuesta te lo doy por aceptada, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

con los formatos seguro sale.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy");
```

Mira el link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Un saludo!

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que establecer el formato en tu objeto de `CultureInfo` actual:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false);                    // Usaremos español-ESPAÑA
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy"; // Con este texto en formato largo
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;                    // Establecemos la configuración

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()); // Muestra '22 de agosto de 2019'
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando aplicas formato debes tener en cuenta que hay una defincion estandar

[Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

que ya viene predefinida

Por otro lado podrias crea una custom

[Cadenas con formato de fecha y hora personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

pero no entiendo porque poner los "de" en el texto de la fecha, cuando peude ser directamente "22 agosto 2019" aplicando un formato

```
txtFechaElaboracion.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: Los "de " es porque necesito crear un word con la fecha y ese es el formato que necesito (puede ser porque en mi país la fecha de escribe así). No me sirve "22 agosto 2019". Gracias.